# how do i show a hovercard from a php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I want to make a simple hovercard that shows me the number 1 coming from a php page: hover.php

```
<?php
$user='1';
echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

And show it to me when I hover a simple link on another page index.php using tooltiper function in hover.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {

        // we'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data
        continueTooltip();

        // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../hover.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('content', data).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

});
```

when I hover the link it just shows me "loading..."
why does the number 1 not show up?

Comment: Any errors thrown? Have you tried inspecting the ajax request in browser dev tools network to see if it is succeeding? WHere is code for `continueTooltip()` ?

Comment: no errors throw and the request succeed it show the "loading..." noting else and the function you can find it here in "Using AJAX to generate your tooltip content"

Comment: "Using AJAX to generate your tooltip content" [link](http://http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)

Comment: you sure request is succeeding? Put an error handler on the ajax request to be sure

Comment: am sure the request is succeded

Comment: then provide a demo that replicates this. Can make ajax requests in most code sharing sites like plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net and that plugin is likely available on a cdn like cdn.js